# Class table Inheritance, runtime schema changes and ORM

Tags: sql, orm

I am thinking about a model for product attributes. Class Table inheritance looks great, but I'm wondering if it is possible to use an ORM with such a model.

If you take the example of a commerce software, the vendor may want to create new product types (ie new tables).

Example :

```
product {
  id,
  name,
  creation_date
}
```

The vendor creates a new tshirts type, it creates the table :

```
product_tshirts {
  product_id (fk to a product in the products table),
  size,
  color
}
```

The ORM must adapt to runtime schema changes (ie having some kind of dynamic entity that can be mapped to any product table).

It should be possible to do :

```
// Should return all tshirts having a size = 10
tshirts = orm->find('tshirts', 'size', 10)
```

And if you use a convention for table names like product_*

```
// Should return all products from different tables having a "size" column
// and a size = 10
products = orm->find('size', 10)
```

I'm wondering if such an ORM exist (no matter the language, it's just for the information).

Comment: Surely new product types are not a new table, but an entry in the table `product_types`.